# Macro broken after server migration

Tags: excel, vba

After migrating my files from one server to another (the network location of the files has changed and my computer is different also) I get the following error when I run a macro in an Excel workbook named `control_reativa.xlsm`:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Cannot open PivotTable source file 'F:\Tools\Tecnica[Medidas Tecnica
>   (2012-2013)v4.0.xlsm]F2013'.

It seems I need to add access to the other `.xlsm` file but I can't figure how to achieve this. I've been looking all over and have read that I need to add  `Extensibility 5.3` Library to the project but this doesn't seem the solution since I've never required something like that in the other computer/network.

Comment: Have you checked macro for hardcoded paths? Have you tried open book with expected pivot table and run macro with book opened?

Comment: Well, i've tried it right now and it didnt work as i expected, because the macro tries to open that file in a defined path. The thing is i don't know how to change this path since it isn't written in the source code.

Comment: Go to pivot table and choose "Change data source"

Comment: Oh :o what a easy solution. 
I didn't realized it could be that and start googeling around.
thanks for all.